# How to hook BlockIo protocol correctly?

Tags: uefi

I want to hook all the BlockIo protocols,but I don't know whether the BlockIo protocol of logical partions is produced based on the BlockIo protocol of the hardware device which the logical partions belongs to! My hook code is shown as follow.

```
EFI_BLOCK_IO_PROTOCOL* OldBlockIO=NULL;
EFI_BLOCK_IO_PROTOCOL* NewBlockIO=NULL;
EFI_STATUS EFIAPI NewReadBlocks(IN EFI_BLOCK_IO_PROTOCOL *This,IN UINT32 MediaId,IN EFI_LBA LBA,IN UINTN BufferSize,OUT VOID *Buffer)
{
    //do other things
    return OldBlockIO->ReadBlocks(OldBlockIO,MediaId,LBA,BufferSize,Buffer);
}

EFI_STATUS EFIAPI NewWriteBlocks(IN EFI_BLOCK_IO_PROTOCOL *This,IN UINT32 MediaId,IN EFI_LBA LBA,IN UINTN BufferSize,IN VOID *Buffer)
{
    //do other things
    return OldBlockIO->WriteBlocks(OldBlockIO,OldBlockIO->Media->MediaId,LBA,BufferSize,Buffer);
}

EFI_STATUS EFIAPI HookBlockIOProtocol()
{
    EFI_STATUS Status=EFI_SUCCESS;
    /*
    Allocating memory for NewBlockIO
    copy OldBlockIo to NewBlockIo
    */

    //overridde the members
    NewBlockIO->ReadBlocks=(EFI_BLOCK_READ)NewReadBlocks;
    NewBlockIO->WriteBlocks=(EFI_BLOCK_WRITE)NewWriteBlocks;

    //hook block io using ReinstallProtocolInterface boot service
    Status=gBS->ReinstallProtocolInterface(BlockControllerHandles[0],&gEfiBlockIoProtocolGuid,(VOID*)OldBlockIO[0],(VOID*)NewBlockIO[0]);

    if (EFI_ERROR(Status)) 
    {
        gBS->FreePool((VOID*)NewBlockIO[0]);
        Print(L"(HookBlockIOProtocol0:Print)gBS->ReinstallProtocolInterface for BlockControllerHandles[0]=%p failed,status=%d.\r\n",BlockControllerHandles[0],Status);
        PauseProgram();
    }

    return Status;
}
```

Comment: Could you reword that as a question, describing a specific outcome you are looking for?

Comment: I have reword it!  the hook code hasn't worked correctly.